# Issue with abe.jar

Tags: command-line, 22.04, java

When using the following commands in the Ubuntu 22.04 terminal, I get an error message saying the abe command isn’t found and should be installed.

```
chmod +x abe.jar
java -jar abe.jar
abe unpack color.note.adb
```

I shouldn’t need an abe command as far as I can tell, I have an `abe.jar` file (I opened the folder in terminal, the folder only has `abe.jar` and `color.note.adb`) and I’m trying to tell the terminal to use it. The last command (`abe unpack color.note.adb`) is what I can't get to work. What did I do wrong?

(I'm not copy pasting the specific error message because it's in my language, which isn't English)